# Messenger speak to text functionality in custom application

Tags: android, google-glass

I am trying to recreate a function used in google's messenger app inside of my own application.

The functionality is shown here: https://support.google.com/glass/answer/3086044?hl=en

Specifically, "Your spoken message is transcribed into text and a preview of your message will appear in the display."

Is there anyway to access this functionality outside of the messenger application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's alright everyone. You can use Android's native API to achieve the same affect. Here is where i found my answer.
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-speech-to-text-api/